# Laravel blade file input does not get ID attribute

Tags: php, laravel, forms, homestead

In my blade I have this line of code:

`{!! Form::file('motivation', old('motivation'), ['id' => 'inputGroupMotivation', 'class' => 'custom-file-input']) !!}`

As you can see i set an id by doing `'id' => 'inputGroupMotivation'`. However when I go to the page where this blade is rendered it outputs this:

`<input name="motivation" type="file">`

How come it does not take the id and class attributes I've set in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not personally used the `Form` facade in Laravel, however from briefly looking at the documentation, it seems that the syntax for the `file` method is a bit different from regular input methods such as `text`. Namely, the second parameter is not the old value, but the list of attributes you would want to pass.

In your case you would this code instead:

```
{!! Form::file('motivation', ['id' => 'inputGroupMotivation', 'class' => 'custom-file-input']) !!}
```

For more information, take a look at the LaravelCollective's [documentation page](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html).